# Qual problema com o algoritmo Bubble Sort?

Tags: c, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Estou criando um código com o algoritmo `Bubble Sort`, porém ao compilar eu recebo `errors`, os quais são:

```
   In function 'int main()': 16 33  
    [Error] cannot convert 'int*' to 'int**' for argument '1' to 'int bubbleSort(int**, int*, int*, int*)' In function 'int bubbleSort(int**, int*, int*, int*)': 23    13  
    [Error] invalid types 'int**[int*]' for array subscript 23  23  
    [Error] invalid types 'int**[int*]' for array subscript 24  16  
    [Error] cannot convert 'int**' to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'void troca(int*, int*)
```

**Segue o meu código:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void troca(int *a, int *b);
int bubbleSort(int *vec[5],int *a, int *b,int *qtd);

int main(){
    int vet[5] = {4,7,1,13,5};
    int i, j, qtd;
    printf("[");
    for(int i= 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf(" %d",vet[i]);
    }
    printf(" ]");

    bubbleSort(&vet[5], &i,&j, &qtd);

}

int bubbleSort(int *vec[5],int *a, int *b, int *qtd){
    for(*a = 0; *a < 5; *a++){
        for(*b = *a + 1; *b <= 5; *b++){
            if(*vec[a] > *vec[b]){
                troca(&a,&b);
                qtd++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("[");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%d ",vec[i]);
    }
    printf("]");
    printf("Trocas: %d",*qtd);
}

void troca(int *a, int *`insira o código aqui`b){
    int aux;
    aux = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = aux;
}
```

Comment: Tente sempre incluir o erro sendo retornado, facilita o processo para te ajudar.

Comment: Sua função troca está sendo chamada com os índices e não com as posições efetivas do vetor. Tente troca(&vec[a], &vec[b]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não vale a pena detalhar tudo que está errado, programa corrigido.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void troca(int *a, int *b);
int bubbleSort(int *vec);

int main(void)
{
  int i;
  int vet[5] = { 4, 7, 1, 13, 5 };

  printf("*\n");
  printf("* antes [");
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    printf(" %d",vet[i]);
  printf(" ]\n");

  bubbleSort(vet);

  printf("*\n");
  printf("* depois [");
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    printf(" %d",vet[i]);
  printf(" ]\n");

  printf("*\n");
}

int bubbleSort(int* vec)
{
  int i, j, qtd = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    for (j = i + 1; j < 5; j++)
    {
      if (vec[i] > vec[j])
      {
        troca(&vec[i], &vec[j]);
        qtd++;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("*\n");
  printf("* trocas: %d\n", qtd);
}

void troca(int* a, int* b)
{
  int aux;
  aux = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = aux;
  printf("* trocou %d por %d\n", *b, *a);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lei atentamente o que o seu **IDE** está te dizendo:

```
 In function 'int main()': 16 33  
    [Error] cannot convert 'int*' to 'int**' for argument '1' to 'int bubbleSort(int**, int*, int*, int*)' In function 'int bubbleSort(int**, int*, int*, int*)': 23    13  
    [Error] invalid types 'int**[int*]' for array subscript 23  23  
    [Error] invalid types 'int**[int*]' for array subscript 24  16  
    [Error] cannot convert 'int**' to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'void troca(int*, int*)
```

**O seu problema é o seguinte:**

> Problemas de conversão inválida de um ponteiro do tipo `integer` para um ponteiro para ponteiro do mesmo tipo e tipos diferentes, na sua função `bubbleSort()` e na sua função `troca()`.

Eu sugiro para você que pare de tentar entender e ou fazer este algoritmo e leia desde o básico os seguintes assuntos:

- a) Raciocínio Lógico
- b) Desenvolvimento com C desde o básico até o avançado

Após estas leituras e realmente estar ciente e sabendo o que faz, você deve ler sobre o seguinte assunto para poder compreender este algoritmo:

- Projeto e Análise de Algoritmo

Mas para matar a sua curiosidade eu irei deixar o algoritmo original do `bubbleSort`, segue abaixo.

**Pseudocódigo**

```
procedure bubbleSort( A : lista de itens ordenaveis ) defined as:
  do
    trocado := false
    for each i in 0 to length( A ) - 2 do:
      // verificar se os elementos estão na ordem certa
      if A[ i ] > A[ i + 1 ] then
        // trocar elementos de lugar
        trocar( A[ i ], A[ i + 1 ] )
        trocado := true
      end if
    end for
  // enquanto houver elementos sendo reordenados.
  while trocado
end procedure
```

**Em C:**

```
void bubble_sort (int vetor[], int n) {
    int k, j, aux;

    for (k = 1; k < n; k++) {
        printf("\n[%d] ", k);

        for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
            printf("%d, ", j);

            if (vetor[j] > vetor[j + 1]) {
                aux          = vetor[j];
                vetor[j]     = vetor[j + 1];
                vetor[j + 1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
```

O algoritmo acima compila normalmente e até retorna o resultado esperado (um vetor ordenado) mas ele percorre o vetor por completo mesmo quando ele já foi ordenado. Me refiro ao laço for mais interno.

Se você pedir para imprimir as variáveis de iteração `k` e `j`, você terá o seguinte **output**:

```
[1] 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
[2] 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
[3] 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
[4] 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
[5] 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
[6] 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
[7] 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
```

**Fontes:**

> - [EXEMPLOS DA UTILIZAÇÃO DO BUBBLE_SORTE](http://www.devfuria.com.br/logica-de-programacao/exemplos-na-linguagem-c-do-algoritmo-bubble-sort/)

Answer (score 1):

Cara, acho que você criou até bastante código pra tentar fazer o método. Fiz um na faculdade, onde ele mostra como o vetor fica em cada passo de ordenação, se quiser usar de exemplo ou "motivação" para adequação no seu fique a vontade ( creio que você vai conseguir achar onde errou também ao analisar o código ).

Método Bolha:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

main()
{
    int vet[10], i, fim, aux, trocou;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        vet[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
        printf("%d  ", vet[i]);
    }
    getchar();

    // ordenação bolha

    for (fim = 8; fim >= 0; fim--) // número de passos (controle do final de cada passo)
    {
        trocou = 0; // não trocou
        for (i = 0; i <= fim; i++) // número de possíveis trocas
        {
            if (vet[i] > vet[i + 1])
            {
                aux = vet[i];
                vet[i] = vet[i + 1];
                vet[i + 1] = aux;
                trocou = 1; // efetuou uma troca
            }
        }

        if (!trocou) // se não trocou, sair.
            break;

        // mostrar o vetor após cada passo
        printf("\n");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            printf("%d  ", vet[i]);
        }
        printf("   Passo %d", 9 - fim);
        getchar();
    }

    printf("\n\n\nFim...");
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Realmente fui demais com o codigo, tentei utilizar as funcoes pra fixar melhor passagem de parametros, vou dar mais enfaze nisso e com certeza vou analisar o seu codigo